# A network error occurred while attempting to read from file ... SkypeSetup

Tags: windows, skype, windows-8.1

Can't install Skype for Desktop on Windows 8.1

While installing, the following error message occurs:

[image]

if press OK then the following appears

[image]

and installation stops.

The GUID name of the folder is different each installation run.

There is really no mentioned filename inside the folder. There is `Skype.msi` file only there.

If run this MSI, the following message displayed:

[image]

Currently Skype is installed but stopped to work -- this is why I am trying to reinstall.

Comment: Uninstall the existing version of Skype. Restart the system. This will delete the temporary files related to Skype. Now install the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found better solution, then uninstalling Skype first, here: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-to-update-Skype-without-using-any-Skype-installer/m-p/707359

I.e. just extract `EXE` file from package and put it in place. Although I didn't find `MSI` distribution for current Skype, but I found `MSI` in that erroneous GUID folder I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything about Skype , mainly the location you are getting in that error window. Uninstall skype and delete all foot prints which were left in your system.I think one of them stopping you from installation.

Answer (score 0):

check programs and features(`appwiz.cpl`) and uninstall skype

Goto Roaming folder (type `%appdata%` in RUN terminal and hit enter). backup folder skype and delete then delete it

Delete any Skype entry from windows registry (type `regedit` in RUN terminal, click find in Edit menu and search for keyword skype )

OR

User uninstaller softwares like [your Uninstaller](http://www.ursoftware.com/), [IObit uninstaller](http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/9483-iobit_uninstaller)

And after this try to install skype again

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is old, Skype continues to pop such errors in latest versions.
I had the same issue with Skype's version number `7.30.0.103` and was trying to update it since a couple of hours. I checked this page and few more pages before getting into action.
The solution was pretty simple, you just have to rename the file `Skype.msi` to the name that is mentioned in the error popup message. In your case, it has to be renamed to `SkypeSetup_6.1.0.129.msi`. Then retry updating/reinstalling Skype. Mine got updated successfully!

Answer (score -1):

just go to the C:\ProgramData\Skype{FC965A47-4839-40CA-B618-18F486F042C6} and rename file Skype.msi to SkypeSetup_7.30.0.103.msi  and run installer agin